# Snowflake Searching string in semi structured data

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table. There are many columns and rows. One column that I am trying to query in Snowflake has semi structured data. For example, when I query

```
select response
from table
limit 5
```

This is what is returned

`[body={\n "id": "xxxxx",\n "object": "charge",\n "amount": 500,\n "amount_refunded": 0,\n "application": null,\n "application_fee": null,\n "application_fee_amount": null,\n "balance_transaction": null,\n "billing_details": {\n "address": {\n "city": null,\n "zip": "xxxxx",]`

I want to select only the zip in this data. When I run code:

```
select response:zip
from table
limit 5
```

I get an error.
`SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 21 Invalid argument types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(11))`

Is there a reason why this is happening? I am new to snowflake so trying to parse out this data but stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has [very good documentation on the subject](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#traversing-semi-structured-data)

For your specific case, have you attempted to use dot notation? It's the appropiate method for accessing JSON. So

```
Select result:body.zip
from table
```

Remember that you have your 'body' element. You need to access that one first with semicolon because it's a level 1 element. Zip is located within body so it's a level 2. Level 1 elements are accessed with semicolon, level 2 elements are accessed with dot notation.

Comment: Thanks. However, that produces an error: SQL compilation error: error line 0 at position -1 Invalid argument types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(4))

Comment: I have been looking at documentation but everything i try produces an error

Comment: In that case, why don't you try casting That into a string, splitting it at the newline character with the Split function and then flattening the resulting array to show you the instances where the resulting flattening operation is zip?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple issues with this.

1. First I think your response column is not a variant column. Please run the below query and confirm

   SHOW COLUMNS ON table;
2. Even if the column is variant, the way the data is stored is not in a valid JSON format. You will need to strip the JSON part and then store that in the variant column.

Please do the first part and share the information, I will then suggest next steps. I wanted to put that in the comment but comment does not allow to write so many sentences.

Comment: This is the result of that
{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}

Comment: So, my hunch was correct. The datatype is TEXT and not variant. You should have a variant COLUMN to store JSON else you will have to use PARSE_JSON. Also, you will have to strip the json part from your response

Comment: Using PARSE_JSON i get this error Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "auth_body", pos 11

Comment: You do not have a valid JSON

Comment: Perhaps then I dont understand. What do I need to then instead?

Comment: You need to get the response converted to a valid json